# using dask Parallel post fit on sklearn predictors (ParallelPostFit wrapper)

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to evaluate an sklearn predictor which I have made over a larger than memory dask array of inputs. I have read over the parallel post fit documentation https://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/generated/dask_ml.wrappers.ParallelPostFit.html and am still having some problems. The following code illustrates the kind issue that I am running into:

```
from dask.base import tokenize
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
from dask.array import Array
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from dask_ml.wrappers import ParallelPostFit
"""
for stack overflow question
"""
x = np.linspace(0,100,100,dtype=np.int32)
y = np.linspace(0,100,100,dtype=np.int32)
z = np.linspace(0,100,100,dtype=np.int32)

Y = np.random.normal(size=(100,))
X = np.stack([x,y,z],axis=1)
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)

#now try to compute on dask arrays over the whole space
x= da.linspace(0,100,100,chunks=(10,)).astype(np.int32)
y= da.linspace(0,100,100,chunks=(10,)).astype(np.int32)
z= da.linspace(0,100,100,chunks=(10,)).astype(np.int32)
x,y,z = da.meshgrid(x,y,z,sparse=False,indexing='ij')
stacked = da.stack([x.flatten(),y.flatten(),z.flatten()],axis=1)
clf = ParallelPostFit(estimator=reg)
clf.predict(stacked)
```

Excecuting clf.predict throws a value error Can't drop an axis with more than 1 block. Please use `atop` instead.

which I dont understand how to correct.
Thank You for any help.

Comment: I recommend raising this as an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/issues/new